# Network Analysis with multiple email recipients in R

Tags: r, social-networking, tidyr, stringr, network-analysis

I'm trying to build an R script that can take in email meta-data, process it into a network graph and save that off as an interactive HTML page to explore.

I started by simplifying my data to just emails between two people (one sender and one recipient), and I've got my script working with that (see script below which loads the data and generates the ndoe & edge lists).

In my actual data though, the Recipients list can have multiple recipients in there, and I want to include these interactions too. The email addresses are separated by spaces, so I should be able to separate them out quite easily, I just can't see how to do it!

```
####Load Data#####
library(tidyverse)
library(tcltk)

#Load Base Data File
baseData <- read.csv(tk_choose.files(caption = "Select the main data file"))

#change all email addresses to lower case
levels(baseData$Sender) <- tolower(levels(baseData$Sender))
levels(baseData$Recipients) <- tolower(levels(baseData$Recipients))

attrs <- read.csv(tk_choose.files(caption = "Select the attribute data file"))

####Generate Node & Edge Lists####

#Generate Node List
sources <- baseData %>%
  distinct(Sender) %>%
  rename(email = Sender)

destinations <- baseData %>%
  distinct(Recipients) %>%
  rename(email = Recipients)

nodes <- full_join(destinations, sources, by = "email")
nodes <- nodes %>% rowid_to_column("id")
nodes <- nodes

#Tag nodes with employee attributes
nodes <- merge(x = nodes, y = attrs, by.x = "email", by.y = "EmailAddress", all.x = TRUE)

#Make graph display name as node label, rather than email address
colnames(nodes)[colnames(nodes) == 'EmployeeName'] <- 'label'

#Replace gender for whatever field you want to group by
colnames(nodes)[colnames(nodes) == 'Gender'] <- 'group'

#Generate Edge List
per_route <- baseData %>%
  group_by(Sender, Recipients) %>%
  summarise(weight = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

edges <- per_route %>%
  left_join(nodes, by = c("Sender" = "email")) %>%
  rename(from = id)

edges <- edges %>%
  left_join(nodes, by = c("Recipients" = "email")) %>%
  rename(to = id)

edges <- select(edges, from, to, weight)
edges <- mutate(edges, width = weight/20 + 1)


####Generate Network####
#[TRUNCATED]
```

### EDITED to add sample data

my data currently looks like this:

```
Timestamp   MessageId   Sender  Recipients  RecipientCount
26/09/2017 16:39    msg1    sender1@sender.com  recip1@recipient.com recip2@recipient.com recip3@recipient.com  3
28/09/2017 13:27    msg2    sender2@sender.com  recip1@recipient.com recip2@recipient.com recip3@recipient.com  3
```

I think I want to try and get it to look like this, and then my existing code wil just work:

```
Timestamp   MessageId   Sender  Recipients
26/09/2017 16:39    msg1    sender1@sender.com  recip1@recipient.com
26/09/2017 16:39    msg1    sender1@sender.com  recip2@recipient.com
26/09/2017 16:39    msg1    sender1@sender.com  recip3@recipient.com
28/09/2017 13:27    msg2    sender2@sender.com  recip1@recipient.com
28/09/2017 13:27    msg2    sender2@sender.com  recip2@recipient.com
28/09/2017 13:27    msg2    sender2@sender.com  recip3@recipient.com
```

Comment: Could you post your data or at least a sample of what it looks like?  It sounds like you could use `str_split`/`str_split_fixed` from the `stringr` package possibly with `unnest` to get it done.  Just not sure without seeing the data.

Comment: Have added in my sample data, thanks for your help. A google threw those up too, but I couldn't work out how to get the transformation to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like this isn't really a question about network analysis.  It really has everything to do with formatting your data.  This should work.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_new <- data %>%
  mutate(unique_recipient = str_split(Recipients, " ")) %>%  #ASSUMING THERE IS ONLY ONE SPACE BETWEEN EMAILS
  unnest()
```

Comment: AMAZING - perfect I included the network analysis reference as I figured people might encounter/have encountered this in the same way before.

Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries.  Check out R for Data Science by Hadley Wickham.  It'll get you started in no time with tidying data in R.  http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html